# How to remote unlocking a fully encrypted ubuntu 16.04 server?

Tags: 16.04, remote, unlock

I want to remote unlock a fully encrypted server using dropbear in the initramfs process.

My procedure that has worked from ubuntu 10.04 to ubuntu 14.04, does not work on ubuntu 16.04.

I noticed that it does not reply to ping in initramfs stage.

Is there a procedure for remote unlocking a 16.04 ubuntu server?

Thanks to all.